# Threejs - How to add bones to an object/mesh

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, three.js, rxjs

I am trying to add bones to a loaded object (that came without skeleton). I surrounded the object with the boundingbox and took minimum and maximum y values, after that I created the bones with

```
let cube_height = bbox.max.y - bbox.min.y;
let bones = [];

let centerBone = new THREE.Bone(0);
centerBone.position.y = bbox.getCenter.y;
bones.push( centerBone );

let upperBone = new THREE.Bone();
upperBone.position.y = bbox.max.y;
bones.push( upperBone );

let lowerBone = new THREE.Bone();
lowerBone.position.y = bbox.min.y;
bones.push( lowerBone );

centerBone.add( upperBone );
centerBone.add( lowerBone );
```

The problem is that, when compiling (ng serve because it is an Angular project), it says me

> error TS2554: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.

I had done different attempts and find out that the "new Bone()" construct require a SkinnedMesh as argument, but I cannot find it on threejs documentation.

Here I used number 0 as the argument -> new Bone(0)

> error TS2345: Argument of type '0' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SkinnedMesh'.

Can someone explain me the right way to do it?